# How to do simple math in gdb

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

I would like to figure out the memory address of the following:

```
>>> ($rbp + $rdi*2 - 8)
```

And then once I have that value, inspect that memory address with:

```
>>> x/wx $address
```

How would I do this in gdb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type this in directly after the `p`(rint) command. For example:

```
>>> p/x ($rbp + $rdi*2 -8)
$2 = 0x7fffffffe43e

>>> x/hx $
0x7fffffffe43e: 0x001b # 27
```

The `$` symbol stores the last value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
(gdb) x $rbp + $rdi*2 -8
```

```
0x7fffffffddca: 0x00000000
```

The address is the answer.